# Check if laravel model instance exists on DB in constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to check if a Laravel model is retrieved from DB or created with `new` command in its constructor?

I've tried with `$this->exists` but in the `__construct` it always returns `false`...

This is the code:

```
function __construct($attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->testVar = $this->exists;
}
```

Comment: plz provide th code you have tried

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: is this constructor of the model ?

Comment: yes it is the model constructor

Comment: why are you doing that ? wrong approach

Comment: I've 2 models: 
`Aircraft` and `Element`, each `Aircraft` must have an `Element`, so I would like to create an `Element` if the `Aircraft` is created at the moment, and I don't want to create the `Element` if I've retrieved the `Aircraft` from database because, in this case, the `Element` already exists

Answer (score 0):

There are model events you can hook into, and one specifically for `retrieved`.

See the docs on [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events).

> The retrieved event will fire when an existing model is retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just call in constructor proper function that is in that class:
Constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = $this->checkModel();
    }
```

The setter function:

```
public function checkModel()
    {
        // do your staff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I think what you want to do is add an Event Listener that will create your `Element` when an `Aircraft` is created.

It could look like this (in your `Aircraft.php` Eloquent Model):

```
protected static function boot()
{
    static::created( function ($aircraft) {
        Element::create([
            'aircraft_id' => $aircraft->id,
        ]);
    });
}
```

That way always when you create a new `Aircraft` via Eloquent, it will automatically create and associate the `Element`.